# Django ORM get average of two concatenated columns

Tags: django, django-orm

I have 2 models

```
class Order:
  ...
```

and also I have a model Trade

```
class Trade:
   x = FK(Order, related_name="x_set")
   y = FK(Order, related_name="y_set")
   price = Decimal
```

I need to calculate for each Order an average of all x_set__price values and y_set__price values.

I tried something like this, but it doesn't work

```
Order.objects.annotate(average_price=Avg("x_set__price", "y_set__price"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Avg` does not work with two (or more) elements. You can however emulate this with:

```
from django.db.models import Count, DecimalField, Sum
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

Order.objects.annotate(
    average_price=ExpressionWrapper(
        (Coalesce(Sum('x_set__price'), Value(0)) + Coalesce(Sum('y_set__price')), Value(0)) /
        (Coalesce(Count('x_set__price'), Value(0)) + Coalesce(Count('y_set__price'), Value(0))),
        output_field=DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    )
)
```

we thus determine the `Sum` of the values, and divide thus by the total number of elements. The `output_field` specifies what the type of output is.

Comment: Thanks it works fine! But what if a sum of Count will be 0? I will get `division by zero` error

Comment: That would give `0/n` Which isn’t a division by zero case :)